# (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have an AWS lambda function in Python3.9 which uses boto3 to get an object from a folder in S3:

```
import os
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client("s3", region_name='us-east-1')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3_buckt_name = event["s3_buckt_name"]
    s3_key = event["s3_key"]
    
    code = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=s3_buckt_name, Key=s3_key)["Body"].read()
    os.chdir('/tmp')
    with open(s3_key,"wb") as file:
        file.write(code)
```

In the lambda test I am using the following JSON:

```
{
  "s3_buckt_name": "iascode-v1",
  "s3_key": "m.l@pl.com/problem_1/code.py"
}
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.",
  "errorType": "NoSuchKey",
  "requestId": "8deb78e6-9dd8-4936-8f35-fd8739510316",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 16, in lambda_handler\n    code = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=s3_buckt_name, Key=s3_key)[\"Body\"].read()\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 391, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 719, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

This is strange because all the files are present in my S3 bucket:

[image]

Whenever I take the "code.py" file outside of the folders and use "s3_key": "code.py" everting works fine. I have also tried to use "s3_key": "/m.l@pl.com/problem_1/code.py" with no success (notice the backslash at the beginning of the key).

Do you know what I am doing wrong? Or do you know how to access sub folders in boto3 get_object?

Comment: The S3 events urlencode the S3 key, so you'll need to call `urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event["s3_key"])` when assigning it to a variable to properly handle the `@` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

**Anon Coward** (@AnonCoward) solved the problem. The error was because the S3 URL had an @ symbol, and the path was urlencode. The suggested solution was to use urllib.parse.unquote_plus, but I was getting an error, so I decided to get rid of the @ symbol altogether.

Comment: I think you mean that @AnonCoward solved the problem ;-)